# Send intent from listview using a service

Tags: android, listview, service, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I am making an app that uses a package manager to find all the apps on your phone and display it in a listview. For now it only opens the app, but I want to send the intent to another class useing a service and a broadcastreciever. The idea is to make a shortcut that launches the selected app with a click of a button in another class. Here is my code:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
ResolveInfo launchable=adapter.getItem(position);
ActivityInfo activity=launchable.activityInfo;
ComponentName name=new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName,
                                     activity.name);
Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);


i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
           Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
i.setComponent(name);

startActivity(i);
```

}
I want the service to be changeable by just clicking on a another app in the listview. I also want it to be saved on the phone.

Are there any ways of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by makeing a SharedPrference that holds the packagename. By surronding it with try-catch I managed it to start the app if possible, and not crash if not. To "remove" the selection, I just change the Prefrence to " ", or something that is not a packagename.